# Python icalender is choking on umlauts in ORGANIZER

Tags: python, character-encoding, icalendar

I am trying to fix ical files I got from horde (recurring events are off by two hours after importing). So I wrote the following script, which chokes on umlauts in the "ORGANIZER" tag in the ical file:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys
from icalendar import Calendar, Event
from datetime import timedelta

# reccurring events are off by two hours
reccurrence_timedelta=timedelta(hours=2)

# default
ical_file="test.ical"

# input file 
try:
    ical_file=sys.argv[1]
except IndexError:
    pass

cal = Calendar.from_ical(open(ical_file,'rb').read())
for component in cal.walk():
    if component.name == "VEVENT":
        try:
            component['rrule']
            dtstart = component.decoded('dtstart')
            dtend = component.decoded('dtend')
            new_dtstart=dtstart + reccurrence_timedelta
            new_dtend =dtend + reccurrence_timedelta
            new_cal=Calendar()
            new_cal.add('dtstart',new_dtstart)
            new_cal.add('dtend',new_dtend)
            component['dtstart']=new_cal['dtstart']
            component['dtend']=new_cal['dtend']
        except KeyError:
            pass

new_ics_filename = "corrected_" + ical_file
newics_file = open(new_ics_filename, 'wb')
cal_as_ical=cal.to_ical()
newics_file.write(cal_as_ical)
newics_file.close()
```

The ical file, encoded in utf-8, is

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
X-WR-CALNAME:Kalender von acme\, admin
PRODID:-//The Horde Project//Horde_iCalendar Library\, Horde 3.3.5//EN
METHOD:PUBLISH
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTART:20130416T100000Z
DTEND:20130416T110000Z
DTSTAMP:20130416T092616Z
UID:20130416112341.10064jz0k4j7uem8@acmenet.de
CREATED:20130416T092341Z
LAST-MODIFIED:20130416T092341Z
SUMMARY:wichtiger termin 1
ORGANIZER;CN="acme, ädmin":mailto:adm-acme@mydomain.de
LOCATION:im büro
CLASS:PUBLIC
STATUS:CONFIRMED
TRANSP:OPAQUE
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

and the error is

```
No handlers could be found for logger "icalendar"
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "./fix_horde_ical.py", line 48, in <module>
    cal_as_ical=cal.to_ical()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/icalendar-3.3-py2.7.egg/icalendar    /cal.py", line 485, in to_ical
    return self.content_lines().to_ical()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/icalendar-3.3-py2.7.egg/icalendar/cal.py", line 480, in content_lines
    contentlines.append(Contentline.from_parts((name, params, values)))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/icalendar-3.3-py2.7.egg/icalendar  /parser.py", line 510, in from_parts
    % (name, params, values))
ValueError: Property: 'ORGANIZER' Wrong values "Parameters({'CN': 'acme, \xc3\xa4dmin'})" or "'mailto:adm-acme@mydomain.de'"
```

There seems to be no problem with the umlaut in the "LOCATION" tag, but the "ORGANIZER" has a problem with umlauts.

As you can see from the error, I am using python 2.7 and icalendar 3.3. Do I need to loop over every ORGANIZER and remove non ascii characters? Or is there a more general, simpler approach?

Comment: What is the encoding in your ical file? `utf-8`?

Comment: acmeadmin.ics: text/calendar; charset=utf-8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could happen due to a bug in icalendar.

As far as I know, icalendar has been just quite lately refactored to handle things in unicode. It has a test suite for encodings, but it clearly is not very comprehensive. Specifically it doesn't test encodings specified in `ORGANIZER;CN` style (see https://github.com/collective/icalendar/blob/master/src/icalendar/tests/encoding.ics).

I'd suggest [filing an issue](https://github.com/collective/icalendar/issues) and see how it gets resolved.

Answer (score 1):

think I fixed it:

```
--- parser.py.orig  2013-04-17 21:29:47.253235481 +0200
+++ parser.py   2013-04-17 22:04:44.323634292 +0200
@@ -296,7 +296,7 @@
     items = self.items()
     items.sort()  # To make doctests work
     for key, value in items:
-            value = paramVal(value)
+            value = paramVal(unicode(value, DEFAULT_ENCODING))
         result.append('%s=%s' % (key.upper(),
                                  value.encode(DEFAULT_ENCODING)))
     return ';'.join(result)
```

See also the issue on github:
https://github.com/collective/icalendar/issues/101?source=c